# Handling singleclicks on a busy uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

So I have a UIVIew that hosts an imageview, where a user can zoom in, and another scrollview which responds to a doubleclick, and scrolling of course, plus some buttons.
I need to show a top menu ( kind of like the Photos app ) where when the user clicks once anywhere in the view, I would show / hide that menu), I am having trouble implementing this because the click can occur on an imageview or an a scrollview.

So I implemented the

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and it works and does the job only when the user clicks somewhere on the view where he touches the view, not any subviews!!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of your views of subview of `self.view` it makes more sense to use a `UITapGestureRecongizer` and then add it to the entire view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


- (void)tapped
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

Regardless of the view you tap on, with that code it will log out "Tapped". You would then changed the tapped method to do whatever you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

when you make this menu, you can add also a semi-trasparent background with the screen size  an the alpha = 0.1 and then when the use touch this background you can remove it and the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use UITapGestureRecognizer across your entire view. The code would be like this in the viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    UITapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action@selector(toggleMenu)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    ...
}

- (void)toggleMenu {
    self.menu.hidden = !self.menu.hidden;
}
```

Probably this would work better and it's always nicer to use higher level libraries rather than using raw touch events. Comment if you have any questions :)